# FindWindowEx Without windowTitle

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, pinvoke

how to FindWindowEx Without windowTitle?

my code:

```
H = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, 0, "TextB", "windowTitle")
```

windowTitle is changed evrey second, how i get the handle without the windowTitle?.

other option:

get the title by classname

```
H = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, 0, "TextB", GetTitleByClassname(Hwnd,"TextB"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `EnumWindows` to enumerate all top level windows.
- Call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` for each top level window to check whether or not that window belongs to the target process.
- When you find the desired top level window, call `EnumChildWindows` to enumerate all of its children.

If you know the hierarchy, or the window class name, then you should be able to identify which of the children is you target window.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one child window of class "TextB", then pass NULL to the last parameter.

```
H = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, NULL, "TextB", NULL);
```

Comment: i tried it, this is not working (It should work, but in this application is not working (very weird))